# FSlex/FSyacc crash - can't locate FSharp.Core assembly

Tags: f#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, fsyacc, fslex

I'm having an issue with FSlex/FSyacc crashing on my machine.

In context this is inside Visual Studio 11 beta running on Windows 8 Consumer Preview (32 bit) running inside a Parallels virtual machine.

> ------ Build started: Project: Basis, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1546,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a". Check to make sure the assembly
>   exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may
>   get compilation errors. Basis ->
>   C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Basis\bin\Debug\Basis.dll
>   ------ Build started: Project: Syntax, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ cd C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\ CALL C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\fsyacc.cmd CALL
>   C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\fslex.cmd
>   Running fsyacc.cmd... CalParser.fsp Running fsyacc.exe... Unhandled
>   Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   at .$FSharp.PowerPack.FsYacc.Driver.main@() WRN:
>   Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. Running fslex.cmd... Not
>   running fslex.exe as CalLexer.fs is newer than CalLexer.fsl
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1036,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "cd
>   C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\ CALL
>   C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\fsyacc.cmd CALL
>   C:\Users\nexus\Desktop\Statical\trunk\Statical\Syntax\fslex.cmd"
>   exited with code -532459699. Done building project "Syntax.fsproj" --
>   FAILED.

The relevant piece seems to be this:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   at .$FSharp.PowerPack.FsYacc.Driver.main@()

Not sure why it can't locate the FSharp.Core assembly.

Ideas?

Comment: we are going to need more hints than this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to install F# 2.0. There was a dependency on that.

Comment: On a Windows 8 machine, it's valuable to install/enable the .NET 3.5.1 component _before_ you install VS, to ensure F# 2.0 components get installed by the VS install.